# Why might an assignment in Swift not happen?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, variable-assignment, compiler-bug

In the following Swift code, for some types `T:HasDefaultValues`, the assignment in `init(variableValue: T)` does not happen and the member `variable` takes the value of `T.defaultValue`:

```
protocol HasDefaultValues : Equatable {
  static var defaultValue: Self {get}
  static var alternativeValue: Self {get}
}

class MyClass<T:HasDefaultValues> : NSObject, NSCoding {
  var variable: T = T.defaultValue

  init(variableValue: T) {
    self.variable = variableValue // Executed, but assignment doesn't happen!
    super.init()
  }

// ... More code follows
}
```

I have single-stepped the code using the debugger, and confirmed that the value of `variableValue` is as expected, that execution passes over the `self.variable = variableValue` assignment, but that the value of `self.variable` does not change. The code works as expected for numerous other types `T:HasDefaultValues`. Might this be a compiler bug?

The code for the type `T:HasDefaultValues` for which assignment isn't happening is quite complex, and I've not tried to reduce things to a minimal reproducible example. I'm asking here if there are good reasons for a simple assignment to fail other than a compiler bug. If there are, this would be useful in reducing things to a minimal reproducible example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us a verifiable, working example so we can verify this behaviour for you. I.e., you should be able to include (a downsized example) of your conformance to `NSCoding` in `MyClass`, as well as some simple example usage of `MyClass` for some type extended by and conforming to `HasDefaultValues`.

Comment: You can declare your variable as `let`, if you don't plan to change it during the lifecycle of the code, this will give you more stability to the source code.

Comment: @Cristik As `variable` is set to a default initial value, it wont be mutable in the initializer if declared as a immutable variable (`let`).

Comment: You can not give it an initial value, and set in in the initializer

Comment: @Cristik You can, if it's a mutable (`var`). This is possibly usable when offering several initializers (`init()` and `init(newStartValue: T)`) to caller.

Comment: @dfri not sure I follow you. You can have an uninitialized `let` and multiple initializers that set the value.

Comment: @Cristik We're probably both misunderstanding each other :) My initial comment to you was regarding _"you can declare your variable as `let`"_: _if_ OP were to change `variable` from `var` to `let`, then he'd break his code, as he wont be able to mutate it in his initializer above (since he _already sets a default value to it_ (see `... variable: T = T.defaultValue`) when declaring it in the class).

Comment: @Cristik is correct: in my scenario, the variable needs to be a var so that it can have a default initial value and be mutated later.

Comment: @Chris: if you are mutating the `var` only inside an initializer you should really use a constant (`let`).

Answer (score 2):

I think some code is changing again the `variable` property.

Please add an observer to check this "theory".

```
var variable: T = T.defaultValue {
    didSet(oldValue) {
        debugPrint("variable changed from \(oldValue) to \(variable)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The `variable` property is not being set again by something else, but the suggestion to use `didSet` has been really helpful. I've not figured out exactly what is going on, but I have a bit more information now.